# Getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" when I have two foreach

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if ($login->messages || $content->messages) {
    echo '<div id="message">';
    foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    } foreach ($content->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Where both $login->messages and $content->messages are arrays that may be empty. When $login->messages is empty but $content->messages is not, things work fine and the messages in $content->messages are displayed However, when $login->messages has something and $content->messages is empty, the login messages are shown, then I get the error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in" under the messages. I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: This code does _not_ throw any warnings when one or both of these variables are empty arrays. Logical conclusion: They are _not_ empty arrays, but something else.

Answer (score 3):

Either `$login->messages` or `$content->messages` is not an array. You may think they are an empty array - but they are probably actually `false`, `null`, `''`, or `0`.

I would check them with `var_dump()` to see their type.

Answer (score 0):

if ($login->messages || $content->messages)
why don't you check if count() > 0

Answer (score 0):

You are checking with a conditional `OR` and then go on to use **both** variables.

```
if ($login->messages || $content->messages)
```

The statement will return `true` if either `$messages` contain data.

You should check that both values are not empty with an `AND`.

```
if ($login->messages && $content->messages)
```

Even better would be a type check:

```
if (is_array($login->messages) && is_array($login->messages))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check a array is empty or not.
You also apply this way that means if you cast any value to an array, you get an array whatever value it was. For instance null,true,false all result in an empty array.

```
if ($login->messages || $content->messages) {
    echo '<div id="message">';
    foreach ((array)$login->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    } foreach ((array)$content->messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```